# python pandas ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

The purpose of this code is to scrape a bunch of data tables with different lengths (different number of rows per table), turn them into pandas data frames, remove some unnecessary columns and fix the date.

All the above works ok except for fix the date.

I tried to reconstruct the date totally by creating a new column with the reconstructed date.

But when I tried this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone

class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\sample.txt").readlines()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def title(self):
        names = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/h1').text
            names.append(title)
        return names

    def table(self):
        DataFrames = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            while True:
                try:
                    item = self.wait.until(
                        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"showMoreHistory")]/a')))
                    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
                except Exception:
                    break

            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
            pos = 0
            for table in self.wait.until(
                    ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
                data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td]")]
                if data:
                    df.loc[pos] = data[0:5]
                    pos += 1
            df = df.head(50)
            DataFrames.append(df)
        return DataFrames

    def date(self):
        Dates = []
        dfs = []
        tables = self.table()
        for df in tables:
            df["Date"] = df["Release Date"].apply(lambda date: date[:12]) + " " + df["Time"]
            for date in df["Date"]:
                date = datetime.strptime(date.strip(), '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')
                Dates.append(date)
            df["Date"] = Dates
            df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_localize('EST').dt.tz_convert(get_localzone())


            df = df[['Date', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous', 'Release Date', 'Time']]
            df = df.drop(df.columns[-4:], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
            print(df.head())

            dfs.append(df)
        return dfs
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 94, in 
>       DataEngine().date()
>
> File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 57, in date
>       df["Date"] = Dates
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 3119, in **setitem**
>
> ```
> self._set_item(key, value)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 3194, in _set_item
>
> ```
> value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 3391, in _sanitize_column
>
> ```
> value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 4001, in _sanitize_index
>
> ```
> raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
> ```
>
> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: the error suggests that the list Dates is not the same length as the df
Try doing a print of the Dates list after the for loop and also print len(Dates) and compare to df.

Comment: try inserting Dates=[] inside the for df in tables loop